# Unknown format with wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am trying to install wicked_pdf in order to generate pre-filled contracts between 2 users on my Rails application.

I feel like I have installed wicked_pdf properly, but I get an "ActionController::UnknownFormat" error.

What I did :

```
# Gemfile

gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

With or without uncommenting the 'exe...' lines (one after the other), I still get the error :

```
# initializers/wicked_pdf.rb

WickedPdf.config = {
# Path to the wkhtmltopdf executable: This usually isn't needed if using
# one of the wkhtmltopdf-binary family of gems.
# exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
#   or
# exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf')

# Layout file to be used for all PDFs
# (but can be overridden in `render :pdf` calls)
# layout: 'pdf.html',
}
```

My controller:

```
#bookings_controller.rb

class BookingsController < ApplicationController
def show
  @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: "test_wicked_pdf"
    end
  end
  authorize @booking # For Pundit
end
```

The render HTML is working when i go to localhost:3000/bookings/135 ...

```
# bookings/show.html.erb

<h1>PDF test</h1>
```

...but not the PDF when I comment out "# format.html" in my controller

```
# bookings/show.pdf.erb

<h1>PDF test</h1>
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you please check your mime_types.rb file in config/initializers path. Do you have the following line mentioned -
    Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf

Comment: Yes I do have this line.

Comment: Can you show the view code (probably the link_to tag in your view) from which you are calling BookingController's show action ?

Comment: I think I found the error thanks to you, I was directly typing the url but when I use the link_to helper and specify the format, it works : <%= link_to "Test PDF", booking_path(current_user.bookings.last, format: :pdf) %> - Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a pretty old question but you can use the `gem wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge`  instead of the regular `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem. It worked for me.